# mysql start: Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: No space left on device

Tags: mysql, apache2, debian, lamp

I have mysql start error:

```
131223 19:03:24 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131223 19:03:25  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 55 4050118616
131223 19:03:25 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: No space left on device
131223 19:03:25 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ?
131223 19:03:25 [ERROR] Aborting

131223 19:03:25  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
131223 19:03:30  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 55 4050118616
131223 19:03:30 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

When I'm trying to do

```
sudo mkfifo /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I've got

```
mkfifo: cannot create fifo `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock': No space left on device
```

Result of df -h:

```
     df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system-root
                      473M  131M  318M  30% /
tmpfs                 5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  5.9G  168K  5.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md0              472M   27M  422M   6% /boot
/dev/mapper/system-usr
                      9.2G  772M  8.0G   9% /usr
/dev/mapper/system-var
                       13G  4.5G  7.7G  37% /var
/dev/mapper/system-home
                      591G  280G  282G  50% /home
/dev/mapper/system-logs
                       15G  7.7G  6.1G  57% /logs
```

So... I have free space, but I have no free space?
Which to do to start mysql?

Comment: Do you have disk quotas active on your system?

Comment: How I can check it via ssh?

Comment: quota: command not found,

Debian 6.0 amd64

Comment: Can I check disk quotas active via another way? Without apt-get quota.

Answer (score 0):

Line 4 says to you `Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ?`

If `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` already exists, this will fail.

Comment: sudo ls /var/run/mysqld/ returns nothing.

Answer (score -1):

What are the permissions on that directory? /var/run/mysqld ?
They should be owned by mysql but in some cases I've found that it may not run as mysql either. If not, run a `chown USER /var/run/mysqld` where USER is you. :P

Hope this helps.